# unable to open cloudera manager 7180 port using AWS public DNS on web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Trying to install cloudera distribution on AWS ubuntu instance. successfully installed cloudera manager using below commands:

```
$ wget https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/installer/latest/cloudera-manager-installer.bin
$ chmod u+x cloudera-manager-installer.bin
$ sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

Now trying to open port 7180 using aws public DNS on chrome browser using below url:

```
http://ec2-52-33-212-136.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7180
https://ec2-52-33-212-136.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7180
```

but it is not connecting to above urls.

I could able to perform "ssh ec2-52-33-212-136.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" successfully but unable to connect the same using above urls with 7180 port on web browser.

Could anyone please suggest me to connect the same to 7180 port using aws public dns name.

Comment: FWIW, have you seen Cloudera Atlus product?

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the EC2 instance and run something like

```
curl http://localhost:7180
```

If comes back with a response check your **security group has ingress open for port 7180.**   Note that Cloudera Manager runs https on port 7183 so you're https link would not work even if it were open (but your 7180 should work).

If curl doesn't come back with a response, you can look at the logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log